# Reload page if navigation fail in WebView Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, webview

I'm trying to figure out how can I reload page automatically if WebView fail to reach URL. I don't know if `onWebResourceError` can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: adding the try catch will help.

Comment: you mean adding try/catch in controller.loadurl or in onPageFinished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `onWebResourceError` was the key.

here is the solution:

```
onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {
  _myController.loadUrl("http://connectivitycheck.gstatic.com/generate_204");
},
```