# how to load html from assets when webview fails to load in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, assets

I am developing a flutter application that uses `webview_flutter` plugin. I would like to show a custom HTML when page fails to load so this is my code:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return SafeArea(
  child: WebView(
    initialUrl: widget.url,
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true,
    debuggingEnabled: true,
    userAgent: "",
    onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
      webViewController = controller;
    },
    initialMediaPlaybackPolicy: AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow,
    onWebResourceError: (webResourceError) {
      webViewController?.loadFlutterAsset("assets/error.html");
    },
  ),
);
}
```

The `onWebResourceError` callback is called before `onWebViewCreated` so I cannot get the controller

how to solve it, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an old `issue`.
Your solution seems to be the only one working for the moment as this guy is doing the same here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635976/2976299

Comment: My problem is how to get the controller